# com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar creating cluster scoped datasource

Tags: websphere

I am trying to implement "JDBCResourcesWithJMX" sample . In comment it is stated that "code may be configured to: - Create either node or server scoped objects -"

"is there any workaround for using it "cluster" scoped?"
my code part for cluster is below

```
AdminClient adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps);

        Session session = new Session();

        // use node scope to create config objects
        ObjectName scope = null;
        if (createNodeScopedCfgObjs) {
            scope = ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "Node", null);
        } else { // unless server scope is configured           
            scope = ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "Cluster", "ClusterName");
        }
```

when I pass "cluster" as scoped objects I am getting the below error...

```
[1/15/18 17:17:55:451 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidConfigDataTypeException: ADMG0007E: The configuration data type Cluster is not valid.
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.DocAccessor.getTypedObjects(DocAccessor.java:533)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.getAllBasic(ConfigServiceImpl.java:2601)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.queryConfigObjects(ConfigServiceImpl.java:953)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:460 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:426)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:92)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:461 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:488)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:462 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:324)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:463 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:463 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
[1/15/18 17:17:55:463 TRT] 000001dd SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:522)""
```

Comment: You should be able to.  Can you provide the changes you made to the `JDBCResourcesWithJMX` sample?

Comment: As Alex said, assuming you have properly created the cluster you should be able to create a cluster scoped jdbc provider.  Having done so, you will need to insure the jdbc driver exists at the same configured location on each of the node agent machines.  Are you trying to execute the sample at the deployment manager, node agent, server or ??

Answer (score 0):

ServerCluster is the keyword. below is the complete code

```
scope = ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "ServerCluster", "ClusterName");
```